# I am facing issues while passing ansible-vault encrypted password variable as param into a powershell script while executing it

Tags: ansible, powershell-3.0

I am using win_shell module in my playbook to execute a powershell script, however the script needs a password to connect to the database, below is the chunk of script,

```
& $env:JAVA_HOME\java -cp $liquibaseClasspath `
  liquibase.integration.commandline.Main `
  --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/SOP `
  --username=$username `
  --password=$sop_password `
  --changeLogFile=changelog-master.xml `
  --verbose=true `
  status
```

in my playbook.yml
I have

```
    - name:
      win_shell: |
       $secure_password = '{{ sop_password }}'
       
       '{{ liquibase_install_dir }}\liquibase-3.8.8\lb_status.ps1  '
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, 
I want to pass ansible-vault encrypted password into the powershell script which I am calling in the ansible playbook, using win_shell module in azure devops pipeline.

Comment: not if they are related but at one place you mentioned it as `$sop_password` and in your play, you are referring another password `pos_password`. Do you mean this or was it a typo?

Comment: yep it was a typo my bad, I am trying to fill in the gap in my mind while taking this approach to pass the database password as a secure string in to the command line where the lb_status.ps1 powershell script takes in the database password as encrypted and reads it while it passes the database username and password to the command line as an argument `$env:JAVA_HOME\java -cp $liquibaseClasspath` on a windows host, so basically, the flow of the whole liquibase deploy process is  




**azure-devops { ansible playbook ( powershell script [ windows server ] )}**

Comment: using ansible's `win_shell` module to execute the **powershell script**, and pass the database password which is encrypted by **ansible_vault**  but when I pass it into the command line the **win_shell** decrypts it in the azure devops console and the password becomes visible when executing the playbook, any solution to secure the password all the way from **azure_devops --> ansible --> powershell script --> windows database host**